# Question based on profit loss and SP/CP

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Andrew buys mangoes at Rs. 200 per hundred. At what price should he sell a gross in order to make a profit of 20% in spite of 20% decay( Here one gross means= 12 dozens)

Cost price of 1 mango will be Rs. 2
remaining mangoes= $80$
Selling price of 80 mangoes= $80*120/100*2=192$
What to do next? I am stuck after this

Comment: To sell one gross you need $ 12*12*1.2=172.8$ mangoes due to decays. In proportion to one hundred you pay those mangoes Rs 345.6, if you want 20% profit, multiply by $1.2$ so the gross price is Rs. 414.72

Comment: I didn't understand this. Can you please elaborate it a bit more. I am pretty weak at it. @N74

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: From the very first line. We aren't selling 12*12 mangoes. 20% is decayed. @N74

Comment: That's why, to sell a gross we need 172.8 mangoes

Comment: This is tough for me @N74

Comment: Anyway I think Jens is right, you shouldn't multiply by 1.2 but divide by 0.8

Answer (score 1):

If he buys $N$ mangoes and $20$% are decayed, he can only sell $0.8N$ mangoes. If he wants to sell $144$ mangoes, then $0.8N = 144$ mangoes, which gives $N=180$ mangoes.

The cost of $180$ mangoes is $C=180*2=360$ Rs.

To make $20$% profit the selling price S must fulfill $$\frac{S-C}{C}=0.2$$
So $S= 1.2C = 432$ Rs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Price of one mango, according to Question = Rs.2

Mangoes left after decay =80

PROFIT OF 20 % REQUIRED ON ORIGINAL C.P

1.20 * C.P of 100 mangoes = S.P for 80 mangoes

1.20 * 200=240

S.P for one mango = 240/3 = Rs.3

Price for one gross = 3*144= Rs. 432